# RSA Implementation in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I was trying to implement RSA cipher, and this is my work so far:

```py
import numpy as np

def solve_diophantine_eqn(a: int, b: int, d: int):
    '''
    Solving ax + by = d, where a, b and d are given. \\
    Solving for x and y, where d is multiple of gcd(a, b)
    '''
    d_sol_gcd, d_sol_0 = apply_extended_euclidean(np.array((a, 1, 0)), np.array((b, 0, 1)))
    if d == 0:
        return d_sol_0[1], d_sol_0[2]
    return d_sol_gcd[1:] * d // d_sol_gcd[0]

def apply_extended_euclidean(a: np.ndarray, b: np.ndarray, d = 1):
    '''
    Solving ax + by = d, where a, b and d are given \\
    Solving for x and y, where d is multiple of gcd(a, b) \\
    Default case stopping at d = 0, because 0 is multiple of every integer
    '''
    if b[0] < d:
        return a, b
    q = a[0] // b[0]
    return apply_extended_euclidean(b, a - q*b, d)

# print(apply_extended_euclidean(np.array((12, 1, 0)), np.array((8, 0, 1))))
# x, y = solve_diophysis_eqn(12, 8, 0)
# print(x, y)

message = 7
p = 11                                      # Select any large prime p
q = 7                                       # Select any large prime q
n = p * q                                   # Let large natural number n be p*q
t_n = (p-1)*(q-1)                           # theta(n) is euler totient of n
e = t_n - 1                                 # e is coprime with theta(n)
d, _ = solve_diophantine_eqn(e, t_n, 1)     # Solve equation e*d + theta(n) * y = 1
d = d % t_n                                 # If d < 0, make d positive
print(d)
public_key = (e, n)
private_key = (d, n)
print(public_key)
print(private_key)
plaintext = message
print(plaintext)
ciphertext = plaintext ** d % n
print(ciphertext)
recievedtext = ciphertext ** e % n
print(recievedtext)
```

The output is:

```
59
(59, 77)
(59, 77)
7
43
63
```

The strange thing is that when using a calculator, the output of *`C = M^d mod n`* is 63.
[image: Math result]
Even when I step through the program, when all the values are correct, it STILL gives the incorrect answer.

I don't understand it. Can someone clarify how this is the case?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

#### Try using the `pow` function for exponentiation

Instead of

```
ciphertext = plaintext ** d % n
```

try

```
ciphertext = pow(plaintext, int(d), n)
```

And do the same for the decryption.

#### `pow` is better than ** when you are using large numbers, and modulo

It doesn't simply do all the exponentiation first and then modulo. It does them as it goes along. This can avoid errors.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, thanks to `@Eureka`'s answer, I realised that the `d` being used was actually an `numpy.intc`, which was messing up the answer.

Casting `d` to `int` worked, and with their suggestion of using `pow` function, the correct code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np

def solve_diophantine_eqn(a: int, b: int, d: int):
    '''
    Solving ax + by = d, where a, b and d are given. \\
    Solving for x and y, where d is multiple of gcd(a, b)
    '''
    d_sol_gcd, d_sol_0 = apply_extended_euclidean(np.array((a, 1, 0)), np.array((b, 0, 1)))
    if d == 0:
        return d_sol_0[1], d_sol_0[2]
    return d_sol_gcd[1:] * d // d_sol_gcd[0]

def apply_extended_euclidean(a: np.ndarray, b: np.ndarray, d = 1):
    '''
    Solving ax + by = d, where a, b and d are given \\
    Solving for x and y, where d is multiple of gcd(a, b) \\
    Default case stopping at d = 0, because 0 is multiple of every integer
    '''
    if b[0] < d:
        return a, b
    q = a[0] // b[0]
    return apply_extended_euclidean(b, a - q*b, d)

# print(apply_extended_euclidean(np.array((12, 1, 0)), np.array((8, 0, 1))))
# x, y = solve_diophysis_eqn(12, 8, 0)
# print(x, y)

message = 7
p = 11                                      # Select any large prime p
q = 7                                       # Select any large prime q
n = p * q                                   # Let large natural number n be p*q
t_n = (p-1)*(q-1)                           # theta(n) is euler totient of n
e = t_n - 1                                 # e is coprime with theta(n)
d, _ = solve_diophantine_eqn(e, t_n, 1)       # Solve equation e*d + theta(n) * y = 1
d = d % t_n                                 # If d < 0, make d positive
print(d)
public_key = (e, n)
private_key = (d, n)
print(public_key)
print(private_key)
plaintext = message
print(plaintext)
ciphertext = pow(plaintext, int(d), n)
print(ciphertext)
recievedtext = pow(ciphertext, e, n)
print(recievedtext)
```